# Print two results from awk match() functions in one line

Tags: regex, awk, match

There are two awk match() functions:

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

and

```
awk 'match($0,/2022:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

Both of them print required results independently, one matches IP address, second matches date and time.

How to combine these two functions, so their results are printed within one line?

Comment: Please do post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just grab IP address and store it in a variable. Later while printing date print ip and matched date together:

```bash
awk '
match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) {
   IP = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0, /2022:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/ {
   print IP, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach works, however the order is wrong and it gives corrupted results with IP address regex.

I have refined it and this is correct answer:

`awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) { IP = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) } match($0, /2022:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/)  { print IP, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }'`

Comment: Unfortunately no, regex is in both cases corrupted. This is the correct form:

IP address: `$0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/`

Date and time: `$0, /2022:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/`

Comment: ok I have provided both longer and shorter versions of regex in my answer. Does this look good now?

Comment: There is no longer and shorter version. There is only functional version, which is the refactored one I posted.

Comment: Can you check our awk version and let me know. I think it is not gnu awk

Comment: I have removed other suggestion and left the answer with only the awk command that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid adding trailing newline you might use `printf`, consider following simple example, let say you have `file.txt` as follows

```
1A2B3
4C5D6
7E8F9
```

and have developed one command to print first digit and one command to print first uppercase letter as follows

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file.txt
awk 'match($0,/[A-Z]/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file.txt
```

and want to print first digit space first letter in one line, then you can alter these to single command as follows

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]/){printf "%s ", substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}match($0,/[A-Z]/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
1 A
4 C
7 E
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*